# Создание запроса времени последней редакции страниц МедиаВики

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

Создаю таблицу последних изменений на страницах МедиаВики. В базе есть таблица `revision` с полями
`rev_id` - уникальный идентификатор редакции
`rev_page` - id страницы,
`rev_timestamp` - метка времени

Есть таблица `page` с полями
`page_id` - id страницы == `rev_page` из таблицы `revision`
`page_title` - название страницы, из которой формируется ключ URL

Необходимо получить с датами последних изменений страниц вида:
`page_id`
`page_title`
`last_timestamp`

C запросом получения последних изменений из таблицы `revision` разобрался:

```
SELECT t.`rev_id`, t.`rev_page`, t.`rev_timestamp` 
FROM `revision` t JOIN 
(SELECT `rev_page`, max(`rev_timestamp`) as `max_time` 
FROM `revision` GROUP BY `rev_page`) as t1 
ON t.`rev_page`= t1.`rev_page` AND t.`rev_timestamp` = t1.`max_time`
```

Но как к нему прикрутить поле `page_title`, где `page_id`=`rev_page` соображалки не хватает. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итого, вот запрос:

```
SELECT t.`rev_id`, t.`rev_page`, t.`rev_timestamp`, `page_title`
FROM `page`,`revision` t JOIN 
(SELECT `rev_page`, max(`rev_timestamp`) as `max_time` 
FROM `revision` GROUP BY `rev_page`) as t1 
ON t.`rev_page`= t1.`rev_page`  AND t.`rev_timestamp` = t1.`max_time` 
WHERE t.rev_page = `page_id`;
```

Получите таблицу с полями `rev_id`, `rev_page`, `rev_timestamp`, `page_title`, где `rev_page` будет уникальным идентификатором страницы вики.